# error inserting data in magento with custom connection

Tags: database, magento

I am doing a data migration from one magento to another, I have changed the connections in the local.xml so that I could read one bank and write in another one, when I get the connections I get this

**Core write:**

```
print_r(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write')->getConfig()['dbname']);
result: db_write
```

**Core read:**

```
print_r(Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->getConfig()['dbname']);
result: db_read
```

When picking up the user's database everything is ok, but when I try to insert programmatically it inserts without some attributes like firstname, lastname. When I remove the external connections from the `local.xml` and try to insert the data again it inserts normally, to insert I am using `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setData($data)->save();`

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the data you're inserting ? By using the `setData()` method, you're removing all the existing data on your object and replacing it by yours. So if the attributes like firstname and lastname are not present in your `$data` array, those will be unset from your customer. Did you try using the `addData()` method instead ?